# Swift: Make programatic width constraint adapt to portrait and landscape

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have a view with the following constraints:

```
photoImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.width).isActive = true
photoImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: photoImageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.7).isActive = true
```

(the image view has previously been anchored to the top, leading and trailing anchors of the parent view).

The problem is, when I rotate the device, the width constraint of the original orientation persists (If I move from portrait to landscape the width remains portrait-size and if I move from landscape to portrait the width remains landscape-size).

How can I get the view's width to be recalculated every time I turn the device?

When I use collection views I have invalidateLayout() but in this case it's just imageViews, buttons and labels.

Comment: Based on the constraints you show, it should be doing what you want... although, if it's constrained to Leading and Trailing, you don't need a `.widthAnchor`. Is your imageView set to `Aspect Fit` which may be confusing you (give the image view a background color to check)? Do you have other constraints applied to it? Can you show a screen-cap (or two) of what you're getting?

Comment: @DonMag Thanks, I found the issue was with the containing scroll view. I fixed those anchors and now it works.